# How to handle email uniqueness validation in User creation in the case of OmniAuth

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How to handle email validation in User creation?

I am using multiple providers(google, facebook). As because of both Gmail and Facebook has been created with the same mail ID.

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = User.where(provider: auth.provider, email: auth.info.email).first
    user ||= User.create!(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid, name: auth.info.name, email: auth.info.email, password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
    user
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @TomLord
As I have to work on "Signin with Google" and "Singin with facebook" options, configured with all the required steps from gems - "omniauth-google-oauth2" and "omniauth-facebook" 

For the first time, User will be created from the backed model User.rb
`def self.from_omniauth(auth)
 .....
end`

1st time - used Google
2nd time - used Facebook
Facing Validation Error: "Email has already been Taken"

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You've designed a system where each user has one `email` and one `provider`; so maybe it makes sense for the above to trigger an error?

Comment: If a user signs up via two providers, should it (1) Be an error? (2) Create a second, independent user? (3) Merge with the original user (and what do you want to do about the `users.provider` value?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think 3rd option - merge with the original user would be better, as because currently user related provider value is not using anywhere in my application.

Email Validation code in User model as
`devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2, :facebook]`

Comment: As I said in my previous comment -- What do you want to do about the `users.provider` value? If you "merge" the accounts, then you'll need to either (1) keep the original value, or (2) overwrite the value, or (3) change it to a has-many association (i.e. a separate database table).

Comment: Either way, your fundamental problem is that the code is looking up: `User.where(provider: auth.provider ...`, but if you want to only determine users by the email then this must be simplified to `User.where(email: auth.info.email).first` (or you can equivalently use the `find_by` method instead)

Answer (score 1):

How about create another `UserProvider` model which `belongs_to` `User` model.

So, when a user uses third party to sign up / sign in to your system, you can manage if the `email` is used or not to create new user. Then, you create new `UserProvider` record for that user if it's not there

```
user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
user ||= User.create!(name: auth.info.name, email: auth.info.email, password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20])

user_provider = UserProvider.find_or_create_by(
                                provider: auth.provider,
                                uid: auth.uid,
                                user_id: user.id
                             )
```